# how to do unit tests in decorators in nestJS?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs, decorator, ts-jest

I looked everywhere, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to create tests with nestjs decorators, and I couldn't find much on the site itself either.

can you help me?

this is my decorator

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common'
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql'

export type AuthUser = {
  id: string
}

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator((data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext): AuthUser => {
  const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
  const req = ctx.getContext().req
  return req.currentUser
})
```

jest typescript nestjs

Comment: this might be helpful https://medium.com/@enrico.ferro/create-a-test-case-for-custom-parameter-decorator-in-nestjs-7-d97de5c4e6a0 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70110485/how-to-test-nestjs-routes-with-query-decorators-and-validation-pipes

Answer (score 2):

These issues are all similar, decorators like GraphQL, TypeOrm, and class-validator,..
But they all have the same point, it sends a callback function inside the decorator. As all of these are functions, what you can do is create a file that holds all of the functions you'll be using, and you can start writing tests for them. It more easier than trying to test deep libs methods.

In this case, you can try this.

auth.decorator.ts

```js
import { ExecutionContext, createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlContextType, GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

export type AuthUser = {
  id: string
}

export const userFactory = (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext):AuthUser => {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const req = ctx.getContext().req;
    return req.currentUser;
  }

/**
 * Defines HTTP route param decorator
 * @return current user payload
 */
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(userFactory);
```

auth.decorator.test.ts

```js
// Libs importing
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

const mockGraphQLContext: Pick<GqlExecutionContext, 'getContext'> = {
  getContext: jest.fn(),
};

const mockExecutionContexts: ExecutionContext = {
  getType: jest.fn(),
  getArgByIndex: jest.fn(),
  getArgs: jest.fn(),
  getClass: jest.fn(),
  getHandler: jest.fn(),
  switchToHttp: jest.fn(),
  switchToRpc: jest.fn(),
  switchToWs: jest.fn(),
};

describe('Custom user decorator ( UT )', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should extract the user from the request context in a GraphQL context', () => {
    // user info without password
    const mockUser = { 
         id: faker.string.uuid();
    }

    jest.spyOn(mockExecutionContexts, 'getType').mockReturnValue('graphql');

    const spyGqlExecutionContext = jest
      .spyOn(GqlExecutionContext, 'create')
      .mockReturnValue(mockGraphQLContext as GqlExecutionContext); // has complex types for this one so using explicit for not writing too much method not unnecessary

    jest.spyOn(mockGraphQLContext, 'getContext').mockReturnValue({
      req: {
        user: mockUser
      },
    });

    const user = userFactory(mockUser, mockExecutionContexts);

    expect(spyGqlExecutionContext).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockExecutionContexts);
    expect(user).toMatchObject(mockUser);
  });
});
```

Also, it has some discuss at same topic here: [How to cover TypeORM @Column decorator with Jest unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747303/how-to-cover-typeorm-column-decorator-with-jest-unit-testing)

Comment: thank you. it`s a simple solution that do the trick. Never thought on breaking the decorator on 2 exports.